# PropertyGrid.SelectedObjects showing unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I am using propertygrid.I have some read only properties ,when I select a single object All the properties are showing. but on multi-selection only few properties is showing.

My requirement is to hide all the read only properties on multi-selection. please guide me,

Comment: In Single selection I want to show all properties including read only. But on multiple selection I want to show only Editable properties and hide all read only properties

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of `PropertyGrid.SelectedObjects` you have mentioned is intended.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.selectedobjects%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> > The PropertyGrid only displays the properties that are common to all the objects that are in the array. Assigning an array to the SelectedObjects replaces the reference to any SelectedObject you might make.

if you want to only hide `Readonly` properties, you can add the `Browsable` with value false for those properties. For example,

```
[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
public int Width { get; }
```